# how to store and retrieve searched values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application. I have a controller called searches. When I do search, I will get xml from an api. I need to use that xml in further actions. So how to do that without using session in rails.

Answer (score 0):

Web requests are stateless as they are.  Thus, to preserve state(The xml), you could either use a database, or a session.  I think for this specific use case, you will have to use session stores, or perhaps local storage.  It really depends on what you want to do with this data(the xml)

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to use sessions at all, then you'll need some kind of identifier in each request. For example:

```
http://my.api/searches/search?identifier=12345
```

You can then store the XML in the database (or whatever...) keyed by the `params[:identifier]` and the get it back later for any request that passes the same identifier.

It's all on you to store it, retrieve it, and make sure it is secure as your application required (i.e., can I just pass an arbitrary identifier and see someone else's data?)